# Windows 8.1: Non-system disk slowing application switching

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd

**Setup:**
1. SSD with the system and all installed software
2. 'Old-school' disk with data

**Problem:**
Very often, it happens that when I alt-tab to another application (typically to Chrome web-browser), the application is unresponsive and I hear the 'Old-school' disk spin up, rattle for some time, and then the application starts to work normally. Since all the applications are located on the SSD and they typically don't access any data on the 'old-school' disk (web browser for sure should not), this disk should be down all the time. Please, help troubleshooting (I don't provide any HW information as I do not know which information would be valid as common sense is not working here anyway).

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Hello. The HD Tune utility shows "Health status: OK". I also did the error scan and it shows 0.0% damaged blocks. If you want any additional information, please, let me know. I wanted to paste the health info but it doesn't fit here.